# Why is list(Model.objects.all()) 10x slower against an Oracle database as compared to Postgres?

Tags: django, oracle, postgresql, cx-oracle

On a django application at my job, we develop locally using postgres but our dev/test/prod servers all use Oracle.

Using essentially the same data (loaded via fixtures), this command:

```
list(Person.objects.all())
```

runs about 10x slower against oracle databases as compared to postgres. I checked django.db.connection.queries, and the time it takes to actually query the oracle database does **not** account for the difference in time.

Is this cx_oracle? Is it avoidable? How do I track down this problem? I will hardcode all of the SQL I have to to get it up to a reasonable speed. It's taking something like 5 seconds vs .5 seconds.

Comment: I am no expert to comment on Oracle database, but it is in general not advisable to do `list()` the entire queryset, and it would evaluate the expression, leading to memory issues, slowness, etc..

Comment: @karthikr this is code written specifically for the example - I'm forcing evaluation of the queryset. I actually found out it's due to the NCLOB datatype in oracle, which something, probably the cx_oracle driver, deals with very slowly. I'm gonna answer my own question once I understand what's going on a little better.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?